# How to get facebook friends birth dates using Hackbook sample

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-emulator

I am new in Android, and using HACKBOOK sample application for Facebook Android Developers, by click on Get Friends row still i am only getting name of friends but here i also want to show upcoming birthdays for my fb friends,either by using Graph API or FQL

like:-

> Henry

Turns 25 today

> Plumbla

Turns 18 in 10 days

> Craley

Turns 26 in 306 days

Answer (score 1):

When you create the request, you need to add "birthday" to the "fields" parameter.

In Hackbook, it would look like this:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "name,picture,location,birthday");
```

You can see the other possible fields from [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user).